# Asynchronous task that have access to XPCOM components: is it possible?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I need to create asynchronously executing task (pure JS) that is creating and working with XPCOM components (using Components.classes and Components.interfaces).
However, Worker and ChromeWorker do not have access to Components. Also, I cannot pass to them an XPCOM component created in the main thread (postMessage), as XPCOM components are not serializable.

It seems that it can be possible with nsIThread and nsIThreadManager, but documentation states that

> In versions of Gecko prior to 2.0, it is possible to create real asynchronous threads. 
>   Although this can often be accomplished without serious adverse effects, it is far from safe
>   and often leads to unpredictable crashes. For this reason, as of Gecko 2.0, it is no longer
>   possible to pass JavaScript objects from one thread to another, making the Thread Manager 
>   unuseable from JavaScript.

and I do not want to introduce any incompatibility with Gecko 2.0.

Are there other ways to do that?

P. S. I find (Chrome)Workers hardly usable at all, as they do not have access neither to the DOM nor to Components. Why one would ever want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

No, most XPCOM components are not thread-safe so that working with them from a different thread would only lead to crashes (which is why Thread Manager was rendered inaccessible to scripts). If your task contains lots of computations - use `Worker` to move it off the main thread and `postMessage` to tell the main thread access XPCOM whenever necessary. If it is mainly accessing XPCOM then it will be no use of course. You will have to do the work on the main thread and split it into small chunks to make sure that the main thread isn't being blocked. You can use `nsIEventTarget.dispatch()` to schedule the next processing step, something like this:

```js
var thread = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"]
                       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIThreadManager)
                       .currentThread;
var currentStep = -1;
function nextStep()
{
  currentStep++;

  //
  // Execute step currentStep here
  //

  // Schedule next step
  thread.dispatch(nextStep, thread.DISPATCH_NORMAL);
}

nextStep();
```

Documentation:

- [nsIThreadManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThreadManager)
- [nsIThread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThread)
- [nsIEventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEventTarget)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that Workers and my own XPCOM component are quite unnecessary things in my case. There will be one Firefox extension object and a lot of asynch code, split in parts.